# Detect the order of joint array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting

I'm using Node.js, I have this code that takes `duration` as an input from a user, in the format of `d/h/m/s`. (although, not all of them have to be present, but only these letters are allowed).
the RegExp `match()` is used to split the `duration` string into `Nd`, for N days `Nh` for N hours, `Nm` for minutes and `Ns` for N seconds.

```js
duration = '1h30m';
if (!(/[^dhms0-9]/ig).test(duration)) {
   duration = duration.match(/\d+[dhms]/gi);
   console.log(duration); // returns ['1h','30m']
   // what I'm asking for
   // Conditional statements that take care of the time assignments...
```

I want to detect wether the input duration has (if provided) the `d` element as the 1st one, the 2nd being `h` then `m` then `s` so that if `duration = '30m1h'` it returns false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uses ^ $ to match full string and ? optional operator.  You meant to use find, not indexOf.

```js
duration = '1h30m';
if (/^(\d+d)?(\d+h)?(\d+m)?(\d+s)?$/i.test(duration)) {
   duration = duration.match(/\d+[dhms]/gi);
   console.log(duration.find(x=>/[0-9]h/.test(x))); // returns ['1h','30m']
   // what I'm asking for
   // Conditional statements that take care of the time assignments...
   
}

duration = '30m1h';
if (/^(\d+d)?(\d+h)?(\d+m)?(\d+s)?$/i.test(duration)) {
   duration = duration.match(/\d+[dhms]/gi);
   console.log(duration.indexOf(/[0-9]h/)); // returns ['1h','30m']
   // what I'm asking for
   // Conditional statements that take care of the time assignments...
   
} else console.log('rejected')
```

Comment: Weirdly I found out that the code I copied in my question wasn't exactly like my actual code. yet your solution still got me what I wanted haha.